# Cygwin64 after update - bash.exe - Entry Point Not Found "history_lines_read_from_file"

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

SOLVED: See matzeri's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/42611525/4543664

I ran the cygwin64 2.877 setup to update the installation, and there was a new version of bash that was listed for upgrade.

The installation failed with the following error message:
[The procedure entry point history_lines_read_from_file could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tilPI.png)

Post installation setup.log.full shows these errors:

`Rebasing with list /var/cache/rebase/rebase_all, built from /var/cache/rebase/rebase_lst /var/cache/rebase/rebase_dyn /var/cache/rebase/rebase_user.
2017/03/02 22:45:16 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_texlive_prep.dash"
2017/03/02 22:45:16 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash"
2017/03/02 22:45:18 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/bash.sh"
2017/03/02 22:46:20 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741511
2017/03/02 22:46:21 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/bashdb.sh"
2017/03/02 22:46:23 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741511
2017/03/02 22:46:23 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/ca-certificates.sh"
2017/03/02 22:46:25 abnormal exit: exit code=-1073741511`

mintty shortcut flashes open the window and goes down almost immediately.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Update after running cygcheck at Win cmd prompt as admin:

`` `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. ``

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cygcheck /usr/bin/bash.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-fibers-l2-1-1.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll
  C:\cygwin64\bin\cygreadline7.dll
    C:\cygwin64\bin\cygncursesw-10.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\win32u.dll
      C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll

C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

Comment: likely one of the library was not updated correctly. Reinstall cygwin package and any library that bash depends on. Use `cygcheck /usr/bin/bash.exe` to find them.

Comment: The installation runs into errors when processing any script via sh or bash, and I've tried to "reinstall bash" a few times now, all with the same error in the logs. I was trying to avoid purging as I have low rural bandwidth. 100kbs on a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`history_lines_read_from_file` belongs to file `cygreadline7.dll`
that belongs to package `libreadline7`

```
 $ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/cygreadline7.dll
libreadline7-7.0.3-3
```

So you need to reinstall `libreadline7`.

Comment: How did you determine that the error message was related to cygreadline7.dll?

That worked perfectly. I just reinstalled libreadline7 as you suggested and now the shortcut calling the terminal takes me straight in to a bash prompt again. Thanks so much!

Comment: Bash depends on one of :  cygwin1.dll, cygiconv-2.dll, cygintl-8.dll,  cygreadline7.dll, cygncursesw-10.dll, cyggcc_s-1.dll
`history_lines_read_from_file` name already point to `readline` and google confirm it: https://fossies.org/dox/readline-7.0/histfile_8c.html#func-members